# Retaining values of controls in MVC 3 after moving to new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC 3. I have a page (for eg: "Master Page") where I have some dropdown boxes to select values and click on "Go" button (type = "Button"). Based on the selection, I am filing a grid. One of the columns in the grid will have hyperlink. Upon clicking the hyperlink, opens another page (for eg: "details Page") to display other details. Now if the user click on browser back button, the values in the controls of "Master Page" is empty. How to retain the values in the dropdown boxes and grid on "Master Page".

Comment: This question could use more details; ideally, a minimal complete test case to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on behavior of the browser. Some browsers can keep this data, others don't. So it's up to programmer decide where the data must be stored. In common cases you can use the following approaches:

- If you make a wizard, just make some div's hidden (you will keep wizard's steps in there), and make your own next/back buttons inside of your wizard. When the user tries to go back and next, he won't go to another page, but will switch between steps via JavaScript inside of one page (all data will be kept).
- You can do the same, but keeping your data on the server. In this case, by clicking on the button, your data will be kept in the database. And will be reloaded again when the user goes back.
- You can manually save data to cookies. It's okay if you have small amounts of data to be kept.