# How to retain page controls values on browser back button click in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to retain page controls values (Entire application pages) on browser back button click in mvc. Is it possible?
When i searched in Google I didn't find any solution. It's not like some wizard page or application page. In entire page how i will keep

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retaining values of controls in MVC 3 after moving to new page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058811/retaining-values-of-controls-in-mvc-3-after-moving-to-new-page)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `localStorage` with `onbeforeunload` event then:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    localStorage.setItem('page', document.body.innerHTML);
};
```

Comment: I was tried with above. Its working fine but how i will get values if i was edited (eg. In a page a name textbox and its value 'A' in edit mode i was changed it to 'B' not saved then i cancelled the page. In back button click how i will get the name value as 'B' )

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.cookie.js and save the control value in cookie so you can get it back the value on back button also. Let me know if you need more information